# Finding the gradient of $\sin^2(2x)\ln(5y+z^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, solution-verification

In a Calculus 2-exam, the candidates were presented with the following problem:

> a) Let $f(x,y,z) = \sin^2(2x)\ln(5y+z^2)$. Compute the gradient.
>
> b) Find the directional derivative in the direction **u** = $(1,2,3)$ at $(x,y,z) = (\pi/4, 1, 0)$

What follows is what I would have replied on an exam. I ask you to find eventual errors, comment on clarity, and if possible, score the answer on a scale from $0$ to $6$:

> a) The gradient $\nabla f$ is defined as $\nabla f = f_1 \hat{i} + f_2\hat{j} + f_3 \hat{k}$. First, we find all the partial derivatives:
>
> $f_1 = 2\sin(2x)2\cos(2x)\ln(5y+z^2)\\
> f_2=\sin^2(2x)\cdot\frac{5}{5y+z^2}\\
> f_3 = \sin^2(2x)\cdot\frac{2z}{5y+z^2}$
>
> The gradient is now given by $\nabla f = f_1\hat{i} + f_2\hat{j} + f_3\hat{k}$, as stated above.
>
> b) We first normalize the vector **u**. We call this vector **v**. Then **v** = $(1/\sqrt{14},2/\sqrt{14},3/\sqrt{14})$. Then we may compute our directional derivative as $\nabla f(\pi/4, 1, 0) \bullet$ **v** = $2/\sqrt{14}$.

Comment: I didn't check the computations, but I would first say something like "Let $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$" and then I'd write $f_i(x,y,z)=\text{whatever it is}$. The idea in b) is good too.

Answer (score 1):

Your $f_1$ is missing a factor of $2$ from the chain-rule for the inside function $2x$. Beyond that, it looks good generally, I might suppose you are suppose to evaluate the expressions at the given point so given that lack of detail (which many students will mess-up the details so to be fair I have to suppose you might...) I'd say 3/6. Put in that detail 5/6 given that you appear to know the chain rule and the general structure. Perhaps 5.5 would be fair given that the multivariable concepts are on target.

**EDIT:** upon a second more careful read, 6/6.

Comment: Hm, while I can confirm that $f_1$ is wrong through WolframAlpha, I might be just overworked, but I am unable to see my mistake. Let $f(x) = (\sin(2x))^2$. Let $u = \sin(2x)$ and $g(u) = u^2$. Then $f'(x) = u' \cdot g'(u) = 2\cos(2x)\cdot 2\sin(2x)$.

Comment: Oh, no, I am right after all. And no, I wrote down the tasks exactly as written, so I did not miss any details. (At least not the ones you pointed out).

Comment: I didn't see the other factor of $2$ earlier, I was looking for a $4$. The derivative is fine, but, the "details" I mean that you need to plug in the numbers... I see you also did that implicitly as you wrote $2/\sqrt{14}$. My impression earlier was that you had set it up but had not completed the work... which was wrong, you did it. That said, my warning is just to show more work. Of course, this comment may be out of place as you are just summarizing your work.

Comment: Hm, yes, our Prof. has a philosophy of "you do not need to write down details of things you learned in earlier courses, that is, you may treat anything from earlier courses as trivial", in the sense that we are to show how much we know of Calc 2. But naturally, I see your point, thanks for the help!